# How to subtract the datagridview field quantity with 1 and add that subtract to other datagridview

Tags: c#

I have created  two `datagridviews` and the first `datagridview` has the data and the other one will only copy the selected data from the first `datagriview`. The first datagridview has fields **Title**, **Author**, **Pages** and **Quantity**. Now, when I copy the selected data from first `datagridview` to the second `datagridview`, the field **quantity** in first `datagridview` must subtract to 1 and the second datagridview have the quantity to 1.
Example: the field quantity in the first `datagridview` have 5, when I copy that data to the second datagridview the quantity 5 became 4 and the quantity of the second datagridview now have 1..
I don't have any idea how to solve this. Help me?

Comment: Please add the code you tried.

Comment: Sounds like you have it solved. Your question is your answer. Whatever event(s) you fire to indicate when the user moves the data from one DataGridView to the next (via button, drag-drop) sounds like the appropriate time to Subtract 1 from the selected cells in datgridview 1 etc… You will need to think about multi-Selected rows and if datagridview2 already contains the same items… If you are having a problem doing this, show the code that has the problem.